# Multi-Lingual Site using Cookies

Tags: php, cookies, multilingual, wordpress, redirectwithcookies

im a newbie to php/javascript/jquery,etc. How do I implement cookies into a multilingual/multiregional (wordpress.org) website layed out with architecture like explained below?

`http://domain.com/` takes users to a page that asks for which country they are in, they have the option of four different countries, Canada, UK, Australia and US. Then if for example, they select Canada, they are taken to `http://ca.domain.com/` and it asks for language, English, French, Spanish and below that is a dropdown for other languages. If they click english, they will be taken to the final result of a wordpress blog at `http://ca.domain.com/en/`

How may I set cookies so that next time they visit `http://domain.com/` or even jump to `http://ca.domain.com/` that it would immediately send them the the wordpress blog that they saw last time, also would these cookies (not the same one set on their desktop) be able to work if a user is a mobile client? Can I also make a link back to the language and region selection process?

Thanks in advance!

By the Way, I am using WP Multisite for the countries and maybe set up some sort of php translation at the end of the subdomain multisite urls

Extension to question: [Remember language selection - then redirect to home page in subsequent visits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548301/remember-language-selection-then-redirect-to-home-page-in-subsequent-visits)